# Is there a way to load text data to database in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I want to extract information from a text file (almost 1GB) and store it in PostgreSQL database.
Text file is in following format:

```
DEBUG, 2017-03-23T10:02:27+00:00, ghtorrent-40 -- ghtorrent.rb:Repo EFForg/https-everywhere exists
DEBUG, 2017-03-24T12:06:23+00:00, ghtorrent-49 -- ghtorrent.rb:Repo Shikanime/print exists
...
```

and I want to extract 'DEBUG', timestamp, 'ghtorrent-40', 'ghtorrent' and "Repo EFForg/https-everywhere exists" from each line and store it in database.

I have done it in using other languages like python (psycopg2) and C++ (libpqxx) but **is it possible to write a function in PostgreSQL itself to import the whole data** itself.

I am currenly using pgAdmin4 tool for the PostgreSQL.
I thinking of using something like pg_read_file in function to read the file but one line at a time and insert it into the table.

Comment: please check https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/import_export_data.html

Comment: @dassum i don't think this will work as it only allow me to split the data fields using single delimiter while here i have to split using "," , "--" , ".rb: " and also remove trailing spaces and reformat the timestamp string for 'timestamp with zone' format.

Comment: I would first load the file into a staging table with a single column that stores the entire line using `copy` - but that requires you can upload the input file to the databases server. Otherwise you can use `\copy` in `psql` (I don't know if pgAdmin offers something similar). Once it's in the database, you can use e.g. `string_to_array()` or `split_part()` to break up the line into individual fields and insert the result of that into the final table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An approach I use with my large XML files - 130GB or bigger - is to upload the whole file into a temporary *unlogged* table and from there I extract the content I want. [`Unlogged tables`](https://www.compose.com/articles/faster-performance-with-unlogged-tables-in-postgresql/) are not crash-safe, but are much faster than logged ones, which totally suits the purpose of a temporary table ;-)

Considering the following table ..

```
CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE tmp (raw TEXT);
```

.. you can import this 1GB file using a single `psql` line from your console (unix)..

```
$ cat 1gb_file.txt | psql -d db -c "COPY tmp FROM STDIN"
```

After that all you need is to apply your logic to query and extract the information you want. Depending on the size of your table, you can create a second table from a `SELECT`, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE t AS
SELECT 
  trim((string_to_array(raw,','))[1]) AS operation,
  trim((string_to_array(raw,','))[2])::timestamp AS tmst,
  trim((string_to_array(raw,','))[3]) AS txt
FROM tmp
WHERE raw LIKE '%DEBUG%' AND
      raw LIKE '%ghtorrent-40%' AND 
      raw LIKE '%Repo EFForg/https-everywhere exists%'
```

Adjust the `string_to_array` function and the `WHERE` clause to your logic! Optionally you can replace these multiple `LIKE` operations to a single `SIMILAR TO`.

.. and your data would be ready to be played with:

```
SELECT * FROM t;

 operation |        tmst         |                               txt                                
-----------+---------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------
 DEBUG    | 2017-03-23 10:02:27 | ghtorrent-40 -- ghtorrent.rb:Repo EFForg/https-everywhere exists
(1 Zeile)
```

Once your data is extracted you can `DROP TABLE tmp;` to free some disk space ;)

Further reading: [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-copy.html), PostgreSQL [`array functions`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-array.html) and [`pattern matching`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-matching.html)